# iOS SDK 4.3 installation error on Snow Leopard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I recently reinstalled Snow Leopard on my iMac. Installing previous versions of the iPhone SDK has worked just fine, but this version simply refuses to install after i've started "Install Xcode" and aborts early in the installation process. The error from install.log can be seen below. I've read about several people having the same problem on the Apple forums, but I haven't found a working solution yet.

I've tried reboots, re-downloading the dmg file, fixing file permissions with disk utility, but nothing seems to do the trick.

Anyone with some pointers?

```
PackageKit: Install Failed: PKG: extracting 
"com.apple.pkg.DevToolsDocumentationLeo"
Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=110         
UserInfo=0x10041cb90 "An error occurred while extracting files from the package “DevToolsDocumentation.pkg”."     
Underlying Error=(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 "The file couldn’t be opened because it isn’t in the   
correct format.") {
    NSFilePath = "/var/folders/zz/zzzivhrRnAmviuee+++++++++++/Cleanup At 
    Startup/PKInstallSandbox-tmp/Root";
    NSLocalizedDescription = "An error occurred while extracting files  
    from the package \U201cDevToolsDocumentation.pkg\U201d.";
    NSURL = "../Packages/DevToolsDocumentation.pkg -
    - file://localhost/Applications/Install%20Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Xcode.mpkg/";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 \"The file couldn\U2019t be opened because it isn\U2019t in the correct format.\"";
    PKInstallPackageIdentifier = "com.apple.pkg.DevToolsDocumentationLeo";
}
Sep 20 19:54:54 iMac installer[164]: install:didFailWithError:Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain     
Code=110 UserInfo=0x10041cb90 "An error occurred while extracting files from the package  
“DevToolsDocumentation.pkg”." Underlying Error=(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 "The file couldn’t be  
opened because it isn’t in the correct format.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried downloading .dmg from another machine or different router? Seems to have worked for these guys:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9364/why-cant-i-install-os-x-10-6-6-combined-updates

Comment: Downloaded it at work and transferred it with the same router as before. Long story short: It worked :) Weird, never experienced that kind of problem before. Thanks!